# Stuck in a while loop in guessing game?

Tags: python

So I had to make a guessing game where we have someone enter a number, then someone else has to guess that number until they get it right. We also have to state how many tries it took. This is my code so far, but I got stuck in a while loop and I'm not sure how to get out. Any help is appreciated. We also aren't allowed to use return, so I'm stuck. Should
I maybe use a for loop instead?

```
 initial = int(input("Enter the integer for the player to guess. "))

 guess = int(input("Enter your guess. "))
 tries = 0

 while initial != guess:
     tries = tries + 1
     if initial < guess:
         print("Too high - try again: ")
     elif initial > guess:
         print("Too low - try again: ")

 print("You guessed it in", tries,".")
```

Comment: you never change `guess` inside the loop so it never exits.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not taking input within the body of the loop, so the input doesn't actually change. The fix for this is really simple:

```
initial = int(input("Enter the integer for the player to guess. "))

 guess = int(input("Enter your guess. "))
 tries = 0

 while initial != guess:
     tries = tries + 1
     if initial < guess:
         guess = int(input("Too high - try again: ")
     else:
         guess = int(input("Too low - try again: ")

 print("You guessed it in", tries,".")
```

All I did here was replace your calls to `print` with input and conversion code. I also replaced the `elif` with `else` because your while loop already checks that the values aren't equal and the `if` checks if the initial value is less than the guess so the only possibility left is that the initial value is greater than the guess.

By the way, you should probably be doing input validation as there's nothing stopping the user from entering something which wouldn't convert to an integer.

Comment: Within the whole loop if/else block, you should be updating `guess` not ,`initial`

Comment: Thank you! The only problem now is that it's giving me the wrong number of tries at the very end - it's adding one more try than there was. Would you know why that is?

Comment: @stickseason I would actually think you'd have the opposite of that problem. If you guessed the value in one try then `tries` would have a value of 0. Similarly, if you guess on the second try, `tries` would have a value of 1. You could fix this by initializing `tries` to 1.